# Accessing UITableViewCell from tag

Tags: ios

I am trying to change the detail label on a UITableViewCell in this way:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[folderDisplayTableView viewWithTag:CODE_FOR_OPEN_FOLDER];
if (cell != nil)
{
   cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"YO";
}
```

If CODE_FOR_OPEN_FOLDER corresponds to a tag, then the method works, otherwise the app crashes. I can't understand why since I check if cell is nil...

Comment: what kind of exception/signal ?  is there any message logged in console?

Comment: Thread 1 (green line)...

Comment: ok, how do you define CODE_FOR_OPEN_FOLDER, and when does it correspond to your tag value ?

Comment: CODE_FOR_OPEN_FOLDER is simply an integer

Comment: before crash can you check 2 things (add breakpoint or NSLogs), what exactly is the value of CODE_FOR_OPEN_FOLDER and whether cell is a nil ?

Comment: The value of the integer is '0' when the app crashes. But whatever value I use will make the app crush unless it corresponds to the tag of a cell...

Comment: The error is -[UITableView detailTextLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x156058600

Comment: well, check answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note that 0 is the default value for UIView's tag property, in this case you should check your tag variable before getting cell via viewWithTag, instead of checking cell != nil, I'm sure cell != nil when CODE_FOR_OPEN_FOLDER = 0, in this case  cell.detailTextLabel.text may cause a crash, here is your code edited,

```
UITableViewCell *cell;
if (CODE_FOR_OPEN_FOLDER == 11) // for example 11 is a tag value
{
    cell = (UITableViewCell *)[folderDisplayTableView viewWithTag:CODE_FOR_OPEN_FOLDER];
}
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"YO"; // there's nothing wrong sending message to nil object
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Works now, thanks, apparently a cell exists for tag 0 even if I have never assigned it

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use didSelectRowAtIndexPath method and then get the number of row and text with tag